# Compress a short string

Tags: c#, .net, string, compression

in my company, we have an folder with several subfolders. The subfolders are named by the ID of Emails. For other functions we need that to clearly find the mail belonging to the folder.

Using that, we violate the maximum length of the Fullpath of 260 character in Windows 7. To solve that, I wanted to compress the MailID.

This example here is working, but it seems to be useful only for long strings, because the compressed string is longer than the decompressed string - and it contains characters like `/`, `\`making it problematic to use it as an foldername.
https://dotnet-snippets.de/snippet/strings-komprimieren-und-dekomprimieren/1058

Does DotNet provide another posibility, especially for shorter strings to compress? If not, we can mount the netpath directly - but that would be a less well alternative.

Thank you and regards,
Jan

Comment: Can you do this? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/06/21/more-on-new-net-path-handling/

Comment: My first idea would be to not use the MailID itself, but a (reasonable) hash of it. That should be a (much) shorter string while having a reasonable probability of non-collision.

Comment: Can you provide an example of violation? Does "several subfolders" means "many nested folders"? "Compressing" string sounds like a wrong solution in any case. You may rather need something like indexing - short folder names and database where short names are correspond to email IDs.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answers. I now created an Drive O:\ pointing to the main folder, so the MailID is not violating the Max_Length. Your answers are greate, but the script is still deployed and not designed by myselfe, so changing it in a way you propose, is to hard.